# OpenSSL rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error

Tags: c, encryption, aes, rsa

I'm trying to encrypt/decrypt an AES key/iv using RSA encryption algorithm using openssl in C.

The decryption is working before storing the encrypted data into the file . But the decryption threw an error while decrypting the same encrypted data stored on the file.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <string.h>

int padding = RSA_PKCS1_PADDING;
#define RSA_KEY_Size 384;
#define AES_256_KEY_SIZE 32;

// testing encryption/decryption
int func(const char* pubkeyfile, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv)
{
    unsigned char  *encryptedkey = (unsigned char*)malloc(RSA_KEY_Size);
    unsigned char  *encryptediv = (unsigned char*)malloc(RSA_KEY_Size);
    unsigned char  *decryptedkey = (unsigned char*)malloc(AES_256_KEY_SIZE);
    unsigned char  *decryptediv = (unsigned char*)malloc(AES_256_KEY_SIZE);

    int result1 = rsaEncrypt(key, pubkeyfile, encryptedkey);
    int result2 = rsaEncrypt(iv, pubkeyfile, encryptediv);

    serialize(encryptedkey, encryptediv);

    ///////tested here, this part working fine
    int r1 = rsaDecrypt(encryptedkey, privkeyfile, decryptedkey);
    int r2 = rsaDecrypt(encryptediv, privkeyfile, decryptediv);
    ///////////////////////////////

    unsigned char *getkey = (unsigned char*)malloc(RSA_KEY_Size);;
    unsigned char *getiv = (unsigned char*)malloc(RSA_KEY_Size);;

    deserialize(getkey, getiv);

    unsigned char *ikey = (unsigned char*)malloc(AES_256_KEY_SIZE);
    unsigned char *iiv = (unsigned char*)malloc(AES_256_KEY_SIZE);

    //////////tested here, failed to decrypt after taking encrypted data from a file/////////////////
    int r22 = rsaDecrypt(getiv, privkeyfile, iiv);
    int r21 = rsaDecrypt(getkey, privkeyfile, ikey);
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    return 0;
}

typedef struct item {
    uint8_t keyivlen;
    char keyiv[RSA_KEY_Size];
    struct item *next;
} list;

int serialize(unsigned char* key, unsigned char* iv)
{
    list *ptr;
    char *buffer;
    int listLength;
    list first, second;
    ptr = &first;

    FILE *filePtr;
    memcpy(first.keyiv, key, strlen(key));
    first.keyivlen = strlen(first.keyiv);
    first.next = &second;

    memcpy(second.keyiv, iv, strlen(iv));
    second.keyivlen = strlen(second.keyiv);
    second.next = 0;

    listLength = listSize(ptr);
    buffer = (char *)malloc(listLength);
    serializeList(ptr, buffer);
    filePtr = fopen("example.data", "wb+");
    fwrite(buffer, listLength, 1, filePtr);
    fclose(filePtr);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}

int deserialize(unsigned char* key, unsigned char* iv)
{
    FILE *filePtr;
    int listLength = 0;
    int done = 0;
    uint8_t arrayLen;
    unsigned char *buffer;
    int i = 0;
    listLength = fileSize("example.data");

    filePtr = fopen("example.data", "rb");
    while (done < listLength) {
        fread(&arrayLen, 1, 1, filePtr);
        buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(arrayLen + 1);
        fread(buffer, arrayLen, 1, filePtr);
        buffer[arrayLen] = '\0';
        if (i == 0)
        {
            memcpy(key, buffer, arrayLen + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            memcpy(iv, buffer, arrayLen + 1);
        }
        //addToList(arrayLen, buffer);
        done += arrayLen + 1;
        i++;
        free(buffer);
    }
    //printList(start);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the error:

```
error:0407109F:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error
error:04065072:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_private_decrypt:padding check failed
```

And it fails in:

```
    int r22 = rsaDecrypt(getiv, privkeyfile, iiv);
    int r21 = rsaDecrypt(getkey, privkeyfile, ikey);
```

What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: It could happen if you used different key for decryption or the encrypted data fed to decryption is not exactly same as the one returned in encryption

Comment: I've used the same key for both decryptions (before and after storing encrypted data). Also, the encrypted data fed to both decryptions are exactly same.

Comment: where does pubkeyfile come from? rsaEncrypt? This code is very incomplete

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I've updated the code. My deadline is coming near and I am stuck at this error :(.

Comment: It's still incomplete: getPublikey? getPrivatekey? undefined still. No main either, so no way to see how this is called.

Comment: `strlen` on a binary message is also very bad.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I've added the `getPublickey`and `getPrivatekey`  functions in the question. For sake of brevity, I hadn't mentioned them in the question.

Comment: RSA_KEY_Size is never checked. Do you just assume what you read in has that size, without checking? What pubkeyfile and privkeyfile are you using? Also generated in this program? serializeList is also missing.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I am using 3072bit key length while generating key pair, i.e. for the function RSA_generate_key_ex. So the key are of size 3072bit(384byte) and got the same size while debugging my code. And pubkeyfile and privkeyfile are just the path of  file for private and public key.

Comment: key is a pointer to 32 raw bytes? And iv too? What does serialise do?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, key and Iv are of 32 byte and serialize is a function to store the encrypted key and iv in a file.

Comment: Remove the call to strlen, if the encrypted data has a zero byte your input is too short.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma What would be the replacement for it? how can we calculate the length? Is there any other option?

Comment: you should keep the lengths for all data. If you're doing it right, when you write the data to file, you also write the length of each buffer of data before you write the buffer. So when you later read it, you know its length. For encrypted RSA data it's most likely RSA_KEY_size (almost surely in this openssl library). It looks like your deserialise does not work, and gives wrong length data.

Comment: Code after `fread(buffer, arrayLen, 1, filePtr);` assumes `arrayLen` bytes were read rather than checking and using the return value from `fread()`.  Better to change code to not make that assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arrayLen` is only `uint8_t` which fits at most 255 , so your deserialised data is too short. You need `RSA_KEY_Size` bytes.

Comment: I've stored the length for all the data (as mentioned in the question code) in the function 'deserialize'. In addition, I changed the `arrayLen` to `uint16_t`. However, the error still persists.

Comment: @santobedi you also have to read and write it as 2 bytes, not 1. etc.

Comment: @santobedi besides reading it as 2 bytes, also *write* it as such , so change serialize too.